# How can I make AWS GPU works on the Windows Server?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gpu

I am trying to prepare an **AWS Windows Server G4 instance** to work with some 3D and rendering software, but I am not having much success because **the GPU from the instance**, a nvidia tesla T4, **is not being used** by the GUI.

The **drivers are correctly installed**. They even show as working. After checking many sources on the internet saying that the usual RDP connection does not expose the GPU, I am using now the **TeamViewer software to communicate** with the instance.

[image]

Comment: do you have any solution @guimarzo?

Comment: Yes, I have already managed to solve it with teradici. Please, check my new answer to this question, @shawnngtq.

Comment: got it, I will do some research on teradici. Did teamviewer work? @guimarzo

Comment: No. It worked only with teradici @shawnngtq

Comment: Are there any additional steps you need after you start the AMI? https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Teradici-Teradici-Cloud-Access-Software-for-Window/B07CSG43VK @guimarzo